# Best approach for reading and updating certain elements in an xml document

Tags: java, xml

I am using Java 8.
I need to read and update certain fields of an XML document. 
There is NO xsd definition available for the xml document.
Is using SAX or DOM parser the best approach or is there alternative.

Thank you for your help

Pete

Comment: Thanks Rathnayake  for the response and link, however, my query was really, is there a better alternative than SAX and DOM parser.

Comment: Your question is too broad (lists insufficient requirements to answer), asks for tools recommendations (off-topic here), and has already been covered in a myriad of ways on this site and across the web.  See listed duplicate links to start your research.